# How to store data from a form that POST a request to a remote URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, save, return-value

I am using Javascript to create a post form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function post_to_url(path, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default, if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    form.setAttribute("id", "test");

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "brand_id");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "23");

    form.appendChild(hiddenField);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

post_to_url("http://www.bilpriser.se/wp-content/plugins/bilpriser_value/ajax.php/get_brand", "POST");

</script>
```

The form returns a json file, how can I save the file to a var in javascript?
Thansk for helping

Best Regards / Johnny

Answer (score 2):

Your solution would need the page to reload, since `form.submit()` does that. Judging by your "save the file to a var", I guess this is not what you want.

To do a post and stay on the same page, you need to do AJAX (see for instance [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which makes it easier. However then you will be bound to same origin security policies. If you can do the request with a GET instead of a POST, you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP). Also here will the jQuery api help you.

Another solution is posting the form from a hidden `iframe`, but this will still not get around same origin problems.

Comment: Hi, I have already test with jQuery with .ajax and .post and it's not possible make it work :(

Comment: Is this because the domain name you're loading the test page from (such as your local hard drive) is different to the domain you want to post to?

Comment: Yes it's different domain and that domain don't belongs to me

Comment: @Johnny Ha: Then it doesn't work for security reasons. However, you could propably redirect the data over a script on your server.

Comment: Then you're hitting the same domain security policy. Your options for doing cross domain data transfers is then either JSONP, or as you say proxy the origin from your server.